# Why is "many a man" singular while "many men" plural?

Tags: phrases, grammatical-number, singular-vs-plural

Recently I came to know that there is a construction *"many a man"* which is equivalent to *"many men"*. But I also noticed that the former construction is considered as singular, e.g.

> **Many a man** has lost his life at sea.

But for the later construction we go something like this,

> **Many men** have lost their lives at sea.

I am quite confused in the former construction. It behaves like we are talking of a single man but we are actually talking of many men. Please explain in detail why it is so.

Comment: Take a look at http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25555/usage-of-many-vs-many-a, especially the comments on the answers.  Note that, like many things in language, there may not be a very good answer to the question "why".  Languages don't always follow logical rules; sometimes things just are the way they are.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks for the link. Infact after thinking carefully I found that there is similar usage in my language too. I guess it has something to do with linguistics.

Answer (score 6):

According to CAED, "many" followed by a singular noun or pronoun is equivalent to "many" followed by the corresponding plural.

> many a man tried = many men tried

So, **many a____** is an adverb phrase used as an idiom.

That said, the examples cited above carry a difference of degrees.

Take this example:

> I passed many a sleepless night tossing and turning but sleep did not visit me

In this example, the expression **many a sleepless night** selects each individual day included in the totality of one sleepless night after another and makes you realize how poignant my suffering was, which, I am sure, **many sleepless nights** would certainly fail to evoke.

The expression **many a ___** is more like an oxymoron, a figure of speech that juxtaposes elements that appear to be contrary in one phrase to create a verbally puzzling yet engaging effect to drive home the message.

Other examples:

- same difference
- small crowd
- only choice

Comment: Thank you. What does "CAED" mean? I searched it and got only one hit through the whole site, that is, here. I also googled it and got dozens of different meanings.

Comment: BaridBaranAcharya: I edited your third-last paragraph because it was hard to understand and had one typo (there's no *(b)* after *(a)*). If I have inadvertently changed the meaning you were trying to express, feel free to rollback. Also, as @WXJ96163 says, I believe you should write the full form of "CAED" in your answer, or link to the resource.

Answer (score 5):

In my view, different from the traditional view, "many" in "many a man" and 
"many men" are different words, i.e. they have different origin.

"Many" in "many men" is related to German Menge (multitude).

"many" in "many a man" is related to "mancher Mann/manch ein Mann". The meaning of "manch" is approximately "more than a couple".

Probably "Menge" and "manch" belong somehow to the same word family. But "manch" is connected with singular and "Menge" with plural (eine Menge Bücher, a great many books). Astonishing that in English it is the same, though the two expressions use the same word many.

I know that there are members who don't like when I draw parallels to German. But I see no other way when I want to give a reason for the problem
(many a + singular, many + plural). When you read etymonline you see that this problem is not clarified because many is explained as one word (related to manch) and not as two words ( related to manch and Menge).

Answer (score 3):

This is definitely an odd construct.

- "Many men" refers to all men that have died at sea as a single group, thus the plural usage.
- "Many a man" refers to a group of individual events (a single man dying at sea).

The first focuses on the people, the second on the events.

Answer (score 2):

Many a man couples with a singular verb because it indeed means "**many of such men**" which imparts singularity of every member of such group to denot effect and emphasis, whereas in "many men" there is no distinction among individuals; hence, plural verb. (alireza ameri, from Iran)

Answer (score -1):

This phrase 'Many a man' epitomises the beauty, grace and peculiarity of English language. Singular usage puts emphasis on every individual in the group. And sometimes, beauty and elegance is better than logic.

Answer (score -1):

''Many a'' is a determiner called as Quantifier. It denotes a singular noun. It means: 
being one of a large but indefinite number

many a man 
many another student

While as many as another Quantifier denotes more than one.

Comment: "many a" does not mean what you have stated there. It does not represent one being of a large bunch but the large bunch itselt. Take a look: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/many%20a/an