# “Many a student has passed the SAT examination”

Tags: singular-vs-plural

How can this be a correct statement? , I am confused about the “Many a student” part. Using “Many” & “a” together doesn’t make sense to me.

Comment: If it is any comfort to you it is a correct but not very common usage. There is a quotation "Many a true word is spoken in jest" which you sometimes hear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Many a/an + <singular noun>
```

is used to refer to a large number of things or people and usually stresses that number. It's rather formal and literary.

Note that [it assumes the singular form](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/67294/why-is-many-a-man-singular-while-many-men-plural) and slightly differs from a more common variant `"many + <plural noun>"`

> *Many a tale* **was** told.
> *Many a man* **has tried** but few men have succeeded.